# @JmsListener and programmatically starting/stopping

Tags: java, spring, spring-jms

I am using Spring 4.1+ with a decorated @JmsListener method to process incoming messages.  Is there a way to get a reference to the underlying DefaultMessageListenerContainer so that I can stop/start the related listeners in the code?

My @Configuration bean only creates a factory:

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory myContainerFactory() throws JMSException {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    factory.setDestinationResolver(destinationResolver());
    factory.setConcurrency(env.getProperty("RE_MQ_SET_CONCURRENCY"));
    return factory;
}
```

I understand I can use a DefaultMessageListener explicitly and then use setMessageListener() to assign the method, but I liked the elegance of the @JmsListener annotation.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705545/how-to-disable-spring-jmslistener-programmatically-on-startup