# When is useful use the @JmsListener id attribute?

Tags: spring, spring-jms

I have a Spring App working with JMS (ActiveMQ)

I have the following:

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerQueueContainerFactoryForSection01(ConnectionFactory selectedConnectionFactory) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory djlcf = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        djlcf.setClientId("jmsListenerQueueContainerFactoryForSection01");
        djlcf.setConnectionFactory(selectedConnectionFactory);
        djlcf.setPubSubDomain(false);
        djlcf.setConcurrency("1");
        djlcf.setAutoStartup(true);
        djlcf.setSubscriptionDurable(false);
        return djlcf;
}
```

And about `@JmsListener` I have:

```
@JmsListener(destination="springintegration.queue.local.to.section01", 
       containerFactory="jmsListenerQueueContainerFactoryForSection01")
public void receiveToSection01(Message message){
        logger.info("receiveToSection01: {}", message.toString());
}
```

I can confirm in `ActiveMQ` *web console* that exists in *Active Subscribers* the `jmsListenerQueueContainerFactoryForSection01`

Until here I am fine.

Now if I use the `@JmsListener`'s *id* attribute such as:

```
@JmsListener(destination="springintegration.queue.local.to.section01",  
             id="abc", 
          containerFactory="jmsListenerQueueContainerFactoryForSection01")
public void receiveToSection01(Message message){
    logger.info("receiveToSection01: {}", message.toString());
}
```

I never can see the `id` *abc* in the `ActiveMQ` web console. 
I always see `jmsListenerQueueContainerFactoryForSection01`

- I know that `@JmsListener` *concurrency* attribute can override the `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` *setConcurrency* method

But it does not apply to the `id` attribute.

According with the [@JmsListener'id api](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/annotation/JmsListener.html#id--) says

> The unique identifier of the container managing this endpoint.
>   If none is specified, an auto-generated one is provided.

Therefore

1. When is useful use the `@JmsListener` *id* attribute?
2. Where I can see the `@JmsListener` *id* (`abc` in this case - or even the  *auto-generated* according with the API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID attribute is used to manage the container - the `JmsListenerEndpointRegistry` bean has methods:

`getListenerContainerIds()`
`getListenerContainer(String id)`

This allows you to stop/start the containers individually - the containers themselves are not registered as beans in the context so you can't get references to them that way.

Comment: Thanks, seems it is for internal control, and through that methods I can get that specific data, interesting this approach...

Comment: About `JmsListenerEndpointRegistry` something to complement in http://stackoverflow.com/a/32719138/3665178